# Firebase instance id return null after updating the latest firebase sdk version 71.1740

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

The project is in `Xamarin` android native. After updating firebase to 71.1740 in which Token is replaced by `getToken()`.
Tried all the possible solution but didn't work. FirebaseInstanceId.Instance always return null.
And can't get the token. Any help is appreciated.

Verified google-service.json
Tried the same in android studio and worked fine but not working in `xamarin`.

```
FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.getInstance().AddOnCompleteListener(this);
```

The Instance is null.

Also written

Comment: This method is deprecated.In favour of getInstanceId().Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#public-string-gettoken-

Comment: I can not see it lint warning. And if it is deprecated then what is the other way to get the token. because OnNewToken is also not fired for the first time.

Comment: getToken is deprecated but not the getInstance()

Comment: You can post your issue to forum of google. If the issue appears after updating the version . I think it should be the issue of the package.

Comment: I already contacted with google but they don't provide support for third party library.

Comment: HI, did you find the solution for this, as I am having this issue now

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging to version 71.1740.1
```

And add this to yourproject.android.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <AndroidManifestMerger>manifestmerger.jar</AndroidManifestMerger> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

[(more info)](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/192#issuecomment-629481418)

This works for me (not sure if both are mandatory)